# Dissolving Time Function for Concrete

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base

So I was just exploring some ideas on my own and am having trouble analytically solving the following:

Let $D(n,m,T)$ be the time it takes to dissolve an n x n x n cube of concrete in m molar HcL at a temperature of T.  Find $D(n,m,T)$. Over the temperature range of $32 ^o < T < 273^o$ in fahrenheit.

Mathematically how does mechanism of dissolving work? Intuitively I understand the exchange of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ but still don't understand how to use this to generate said function.